# Rendering PartialView to string inconveniences

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

I'm developing ASP.NET MVC5 (Razor) project. I would like to render partial view into a DIV when Test ActionLink clicked, so code for Controller is this:-

```
public ActionResult Accion(string vista)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vista) || !Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return View();
    else
    {
            object vistaModelo = null;
            if (vista.Contains("Usuarios"))
                vistaModelo = new UsuariosVistaModelo();
            string render = PartialView(vista, vistaModelo).RenderToString();
            return Json(new { data = render });
    }
}
```

Code for cshtml:-

```
<div class="menu">
@Html.ActionLink("Test","Accion","Navigation",new { vista = "~/Views/Soporte/Usuarios.cshtml" }, new { @class = "accion" })

   <script>

    //Dispara la acción en el controlador del servidor
    $('.accion').live("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url:this.href,
            type:'post',
            success:function(data)
            {
                //data contiene el resultado devuelto por el servidor
                $('.content').html(data);
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
        //Se retorna falso para prevenir reenviar a otra pagina
        return false;
    });

   </script>
</div>

<div class="content">
</div>
```

When I click on Test ActionLink,  $('.accion').live("click" ... event is not triggered and go straighforward to Accion into controller. Please need help. Thanks

Comment: The main question - in your source view do you have attribute with class `accion`? I highly doubt that. Also, I can't remember the correct syntax right now but you can try and embed the `onclick` event in the `@Html.ActionLink` code.

Comment: is jquery library included?? and also use ``on`` ``live`` is deprecated

Comment: There is also error in ur controller always return json as...return Json(new { data = render }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some modifications in your code to make it working

** Modify your action to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test","Accion","Navigation",new { vista = "~/Views/Soporte/Usuarios.cshtml" }, new { @class = "accion", onclick = "javascript:return false;"  })
```

Now anchor default behaviour would not work.

** Now modify your Jquery like

```
//Dispara la acción en el controlador del servidor
$('.accion').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:this.href,
        type:'post',
        data : {"vista" : "~/Views/Soporte/Usuarios.cshtml"},
        success:function(data)
        {
            //data contiene el resultado devuelto por el servidor
            $('.content').html(data);
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
    //Se retorna falso para prevenir reenviar a otra pagina
    return false;
});
```

//Add Post on the top of action

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Accion(string vista)
{
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vista) || !Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    return View();
else
{
        object vistaModelo = null;

        if (vista.Contains("Usuarios"))
            vistaModelo = new UsuariosVistaModelo();

        string render = PartialView(vista, vistaModelo).RenderToString();
        return Json(new { data = render });
}
}
```

Also use on/click instead of live

Answer (score 0):

***Some modification on Jquery level***

```
   // code
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('.content').html(data.data);
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
  //  code
```

try to replace 
 `$('.content').html(data);`  to  `$('.content').html(data.data);` Here 2nd **`data`** is the parameter which holds the value on controller.